# How to publish Gradle artifacts without using gradle publish command

Tags: heroku, gradle, amazon-s3, build, build.gradle

I have multi module requirement where the model classes are referred by other modules as gradle dependency. I was using gradle publish command manually. But in multicontributer environment, people are forgetting to do that and the artifacts hosted in S3 is not getting new publish.
So, I am thinking of making it getting deployed in CI or by heroku dynos. I know in Maven we specify in the Build phase itself. But I am new to Gradle and don't know much about it. 
Can you please suggest me a way of doing that ?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why don't you use 'publish' with CI?

Answer (score 0):

First we need to create a publishing task :

publishing {
    repositories {

```
    maven {
        url "s3_url"
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {
            accessKey "acccess_key"
            secretKey "secret_key"
        }
    }
}

publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        groupId 'com.example.common'
        artifactId 'common'
        version '1.0'
        from components.java
    }
}
```

}

Then the following command did the trick :

*build.finalizedBy(publish)*

So, at the end of the build phase, the artifacts is automatically published to the s3, no matter whether is run from remote or from CI (Heroku in my case).